# concatinate array of arrays with its reversed elements in place

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an array of numbers that looks like this:

`const arrayOfArrays: number[][] = [[1, 2], [1, 3]];`

What I need to get is `[[1, 2], [2, 1], [1, 3], [3, 1]]`.

Apparently this can be achieved in the following way:

```
// create an empty array
let result: number[][] = [];

for (const elArr of arrayOfArrays) {
    result.push(elArr);
    result.push(elArr.reverse());
}
```

But there must be some more elegant ways to do this?

Comment: Your solution is elegant: it's super easy to read and understand.

Comment: @zerkms but it's wrong - the *same* array is inserted twice and since it's literally the same object, the `reverse` will invert both.

Comment: @VLAZ right, I assumed `Array#reverse` is one of few `Array` functions that do clone, my fault.

Comment: oh yeah, I've just noticed it doesn't work as I assumed, my fault...

Comment: Still, after you fix it: `result.push([...elArr]);
    result.push(elArr.reverse());` it still would be more readable than `Array#flatMap` (I upvoted that answer though, it's cool)

Comment: @zerkms yeah, I agree.

Comment: Your type is wrong, it's not number[], its number[][]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`Array#flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) and get the result in a single loop.

```js
var array = [[1, 2], [1, 3]],
    result = array.flatMap(([...a]) => [[...a], a.reverse()]);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: @Albert : It is worth mentioning that there's a price to pay for this sort of *elegancy*. I.e. your code may work [noticeably faster](https://jsbench.me/k8k88n3mgf/1), as above solution takes one loop indeed for mapping and ***some more time*** for flattening. If performance is of importance, there's a [`reduce()`-based solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60864701/11299053) around, which is *less costy*.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is pretty neat, but still I gave it a shot:

```js
var arr = [[1, 2], [1, 3]];

var result = arr.map((val, index) => {
    return [val, arr[index].slice().reverse()]
}).flat();
```

Note: `Array.flat()` is new so you can check ES specification [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)

Comment: Why use `arrayOfArrays[index]` instead of `val`? And why `.map().flat()` instead of `.flatMap()`?

Comment: I didn't realise that it flatMap exists. Thanks for pointing it out. @VLAZ